# É Possível utilizar o pyad (módulo para active directory) no linux?

Tags: python, linux, active-directory

se for possível utilizar este módulo no linux, gostaria de saber como instalá-lo?
tentei com "pip install pyad", porém recebo a mensagem abaixo:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from pyad) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pywin32 (from pyad)

Ao tentar instalar o pywin32 recebo a mensagem:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pywin32

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!
Obrigado, Abs!

Comment: Por qual motivo você quer executar bibliotecas do Windows no Linux?

Comment: Anderson, eu preciso validar a existência de um usuário no Active Directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A não ser que a documentção esteja deliberadamente dúbia, tudo indica que o pacote foi feito escpecificamente para o windows:

> pyad is a Python library designed to provide a simple, Pythonic interface to Active Directory through ADSI **on the Windows platform**. Complete documentation can be found at https://zakird.com/pyad.

Há o pacote [pySMB](https://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/) que é uma implementação do procotolo SMB/CIFS no lado cliente, não tenho certeza se ele oferece funções específicas para autenticação, mas há funcões que autenticam, de forma indireta, ao acessar compartilhamentos SMB/CIFS, [por exemplo:](https://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/api/smb_SMBConnection.html)

```
conn = SMBConnection(userid, password, client_machine_name, remote_machine_name, 
use_ntlm_v2 = True)
conn.connect(server_ip, 139)
```

Para obter a lista dos arquivos do compartilhamento:

```
filelist = conn.listPath('shared_folder_name', '/')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Sidon, é exatamente o que eu queria saber!
Porém, ainda me resta uma dúvida:
Sendo um pacote feito específicamente para windows, então eu não conseguirei instalá-lo no linux para utilizá-lo em um import no meu código python, correto?

Comment: Provavelmente não, mas mesmo que consiga com certeza não vai conseguir utilizar, e, na documentacao, diz que ele depende de um outro pacote chamado pywin32 (ou algo assim), só pelo nome ja dá para perceber q nao vai rolar no "melhor so do mundo". :-)

Comment: Entendi Sidon, Muito obrigado. Quanto ao "melhor so do mundo", eu não acho mas sou obrigado a usar hehe...

Comment: @LuisGuilhermeTorrano Se a resposta serviu, considere dar o aceite (No "V" próximo ao número de votos). Quanto ao "melhor so" foi uma brincadeira, mas se vc continuar a usar por muitos anos, um dia vc vai entender, pequeno gafanhoto. :-)